# Show which elements are removed from Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a very simple world simulator. Each time step, people get older, and once they reach a maximum age, they die. I already managed to let people die and to remove them from the `ArrayList`. However, I would like to show which people died during each time step (so which elements are removed from the `ArrayList`), but I don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
for(Iterator<Person> personIterator = persons.iterator(); personIterator.hasNext();) {
    Person person = personIterator.next();
    if (person.getAge() >= Person.MAX_AGE){
        personIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not keep a separate `List<Person>` that keeps track of dead people? Every time a person dies add them to the list.

Comment: in the code where you .remove the person, add them to a "died" list then remove them.  reset the died list each time through the aging loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could accumulate the elements you remove to another collection, and then return/print/whatever it. E.g.:

```
List<Person> deaths = new LinkedList<>();
for(Iterator<Person> personIterator = persons.iterator(); personIterator.hasNext();) {
    Person person = personIterator.next();
    if (person.getAge() >= Person.MAX_AGE) {
        deaths.add(person);
        personIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Now I managed to print out how many persons die each time step. However, I would like to print out which persons it were. I can do this by using the toString method. However, I would like to only print out their ID's, which is only one of the variables, and not everything in the toString method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variety of options, one could be simply having a `#die` method on the `Person` class which reports however you like:

```
public class Person {

    public void die() {
        System.out.println("Old man Jenkins kicked the bucket");
    }

}

//Elsewheres
if (person.getAge() >= Person.MAX_AGE) {
    person.die();
    //remove
}
```

If you need to reference them at a later point, then you can add them to another collection.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list and add to that

```
for (Iterator < Person > personIterator = persons.iterator(); personIterator.hasNext();) {
 Person person = personIterator.next();
 if (person.getAge() >= Person.MAX_AGE) {
  personIterator.remove();
  personDead.add(person); // ADDED THIS LINE OF CODE
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the remove method in the ArrayList class, it will return what you removed. So I think you could have something store the people that die, namely another ArrayList. So something like this should work:

```
ArrayList<person> dead = new ArrayList<person>();
if (person.getAge() >= Person.MAX_AGE){
             dead.add(personIterator.remove());
            }
```

P.S. I'm extremely new to coding so this may not work... I learned how to use arrays and ArrayLists yesterday. (This code assumes that there is a person class that the stuff is in)