# How can I display which elements were removed from list in custom OrderedLinkedList class?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a custom Ordered `LinkedList` class with a nested Ordered `ListNode` class. Everything is working fine, but I am trying to expand on it by accessing the elements that are removed.

This is not a requirement, but I am curious how this would work since I can only use the methods I was instructed to create, which are `boolean add()`, `boolean remove()`, and `clear()`.

I am also keeping track of each modification, which is incremented with each successful addition, removal, or call to `clear()`. I can simply create another `OrderedLinkedList`, and add the removed elements to it, but I feel like I'm adding an unnecessary modification count.

Again, this part is just for fun and not required. I feel this will give me a deeper understanding of creating custom classes.

I'll show the remove and main methods. The remove method signature cannot be changed.

```
public boolean remove(Comparable obj) {

    for(OrderedListNode element = head.next; element != tail; element = element.next) {

    if(obj.equals(element.dataItem)) { //if element being removed is at the cursor
        OrderedListNode previousNode = element.before;
        OrderedListNode nextNode = element.next;

        nextNode.before = previousNode; //places next element that's after before to the element after current element [prev -> current -> next]

        previousNode.next = nextNode; //places prev of next element to the element before current

        element.dataItem = (Comparable)NOT_FOUND; //removed element is now null

        modCount++; //another modification
        theSize--; //reduce the size by 1
        return true; //if remove is successful
    }
}
return false; //otherwise, not successful removal
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   OrderedLinkedList list = new OrderedLinkedList();
   OrderedLinkedList removedList = new OrderedLinkedList();

   modCount = 0;
   list.add("Dog");
   list.add("Bird");
   list.add("dog");
   list.add("bird");
   list.add("Cat");
   System.out.println("Before removal of element");
   System.out.println(list);
   list.remove("Dog");
   removedList.add("Dog"); //not what I'm wanting to do
   System.out.println("Removed " + removedList);
   System.out.println("After removal of element");
   System.out.println(list);
   System.out.println("Total modifications = " + modCount);
   System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
Before removal of element
Bird, Cat, Dog, bird, dog
Removed Dog //not actually accessing the element originally removed. just printing a new list
After removal of element
Bird, Cat, bird, dog
Total modifications = 7 //unnecessary modification due to additional add
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the removed values by implementing an additional **pop** method. The return type should be **Comparable** and when the object to be removed found, store it in a **temporary** object and return that, instead of returning a **boolean** **true**. When the object is not found, simply return **null**.

If the **Comparable** object is found which is to be removed, the method will return that object so that you can store it. If not, a null will return so that you can use an **if-check** for the **pop** method to get that if remove is successful or not.

Here is a sample method I've just written for you;

## Sample Pop Method

```
public Comparable pop(Comparable obj) {

    for (OrderedListNode element = head.next; element != tail; element = element.next) {

        Comparable temp = null;     // declaration of the temporary object

        if (obj.equals(element.dataItem)) { // if element being removed is
                                            // at the cursor

            temp = obj;                     // store obj in temp

            OrderedListNode previousNode = element.before;
            OrderedListNode nextNode = element.next;

            nextNode.before = previousNode; // places next element that's
                                            // after before to the element
                                            // after current element [prev
                                            // -> current -> next]

            previousNode.next = nextNode;   // places prev of next element to
                                            // the element before current

            element.dataItem = (Comparable) NOT_FOUND;  // removed element is
                                                        // now null

            modCount++; // another modification
            theSize--; // reduce the size by 1

            return temp; // if remove is successful
        }
    }
    return null; // otherwise, not successful removal
}
```

## Test Demo

Your test code should be like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    OrderedLinkedList list = new OrderedLinkedList();
    OrderedLinkedList removedList = new OrderedLinkedList();

    modCount = 0;
    list.add("Dog");
    list.add("Bird");
    list.add("dog");
    list.add("bird");
    list.add("Cat");
    System.out.println("Before removal of element");
    System.out.println(list);

    // list.remove("Dog"); // not needed anymore
    // removedList.add("Dog"); //not what I'm wanting to do

    // pop returns the removed object
    removedList.add(list.pop("Dog"));

    System.out.println("Removed " + removedList);
    System.out.println("After removal of element");
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("Total modifications = " + modCount);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That helps, but I can't add any additional methods. I can only use what I've got.

Comment: However, I did a workaround. I created a static field Comparable temp; And I stated what you mentioned (if.obj.equals(element.dataItem)) { temp = obj; } and then printed temp after removing it, and it worked! :-)

Comment: Why is that, maybe you should write a new class which **extends** existing class and add the method on the extended one? Because that your implementation class is not visible, I can only assume.

Comment: If it worked, then I'll be glad if you accept the answer hehe, but for anyways, I'm happy if it helped you. Implementing custom data structures is a very good way to be a better developer, Happy codings.

Comment: Since I was able to use your suggestion with the temp = obj without adding any new methods, I will go ahead an accept your answer. I'm surprised I missed something so simple. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store the elements that you have removed without increasing your modification count, you can use ArrayList and put your removed elements into it. This way your modification count will not be impacted.

Comment: That's true. I'm just trying to actually access the reference to the item, kind of like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698982/show-which-elements-are-removed-from-arraylist)

Comment: I feel you will have to use some other Collection to do this. Or in that particular code, remove the modCOunt++ from each of the functions and put it in main. Then you can do modcount++ whenever required.